# Showing the current location on MKMapView using CoreLocation

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have created the single view application in swift.I placed the MKMapView on viewController on main.storyboard .then i imported

```
import MapKit
```

in MapVC.In viewDidLoad function

```
mapView.delegate=self
```

i made the extension MKMapViewDelegate

```
extension MapVC :MKMapViewDelegate{
    func centerMapOnUserLocation()  {
        guard let coordinate = locationManager.location?.coordinate else {return}
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, regionRadius*0.2, regionRadius*0.2)
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Then i ran project i gave me map of my current location .

**Not Working:**
1- For dropping pin on current location of user and zooming.
I imported

```
import CoreLocation

  var locationManager=CLLocationManager()
    let authorizationStatus=CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    let regionRadius:Double=1000
```

In viewDidLoad function

```
      locationManager.delegate=self
 configureLocationService()
```

I made CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
extension MapVC:CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    func configureLocationService() {
        if authorizationStatus == .notDetermined{
            //app doesnt know whether it is approved or denied
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            //request authorization so location is used always where app opened or not
        }
        else
        {   //is determined means :1-already apporoved 2- already denied dont need to do any thing just return
            return
        }
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        centerMapOnUserLocation()
    }
}
```

**Not Working:**
2-I placed a button on lower left corner of MKMapView in viewcontroller of main.storybaord whose function is to place the current user location in center of view controller

```
   @IBAction func centerMapBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways || authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse
        {
            centerMapOnUserLocation()


}
    }
```

How i can get pin at current user location and get zoom map about current user and location and center the map about current user location?

You can download the project from this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnaDZjck0tcGxneFk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What does `Alamofire` have to do with displaying user location? What is not working? Do you receive an error?

Comment: until now Alamofire is nonfunctional it just make the xcworkspace.I have written the code for 1- pin at current user location 2-zoom map about user location 3- on button press center map about current user location .code is not showing these behaviour on execution –

Comment: Don't know if I understood. Do you want to set the pin on user location and center it ?

Comment: yes.in addition to it zoom about user location.

Answer (score 0):

To add the pin:

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation() // add it globally so you can remove to update location

func addPin(coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    let centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coord.latitude, longitude:coord.longitude)
    annotation.coordinate = centerCoordinate
    annotation.title = "My Pin"
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    centerZoom(annotation)
}
```

To zoom in:

```
func centerZoom(myPoint: MKPointAnnotation) {
    let mapCenter = myPoint.coordinates
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(mapCenter, span)
    mapView.region = region
}
```

You can either get locations update from your location manager adding this delegate method:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let loc: CLLocationCoordinate2D = locations.first!.coordinate
    addPin(loc)
}
```

Or you can delegate your MapView to your view controller and use this delegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    addPin(userLocation.coordinate)
}
```

Comment: there are three error when using this code:  1-  func addPin(CLLocationCoordinate2D: coord) {   // error :Use of undeclared type 'coord' .                          2- func centerZoom(MKPointAnnotation: myPoint) {             //error : Use of undeclared type 'myPoint' .                                3-func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        addPin(locations.first)          //error :Use of unresolved identifier 'locations'

Comment: Again three error but at different location 1-  centerZoom( annotation) 
      ERROR : Missing argument label 'coord:' in call       2- let mapCenter = myPoint.coordinates      ERROR :Use of unresolved identifier 'myPoint'
    3-        addPin(locations.first) .   ERROR :Missing argument label 'coord:' in call .    From this link you can download the updated code having above error in MapVC.swift file [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5pNDpbvZ8SnRVBMLXRUNDZNb2M/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: I found ONE small error of conversion from CLLocation to CLLocationCoordinates2D variable. Your code is messy and will not work in anyway. You did not respect delegate methods. Just not copy and paste the code as we are not here to outsourcing your dev, we are here to help you figure out how to solve your problem, but this task still yours

Comment: You should also state in your question that you're using Swift 4 in beta. Not everybody has the environment to help you